# Программа выбрасывает исключение "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

Вот мой код:

```
import java.util.*;

class MyClass{
public static void main (String[] args){

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int x =  sc.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[8];
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
    arr[i] = x*(2+i);
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
}
}
```

Выбрасывает следующее исключение:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:8 at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:8)

Из-за чего появилось это исключение? Как его избежать?

Comment: Нумерация массивов с 0. В цикле поменяйте `i<9` на `i<8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключение вам говорит "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" - индекс массива вышел за границы.

У вас массив объявлен из 8 элементов (т.е. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7). А вы в цикле идете от 0 до 8 .. вот вам и выход за границы.

Либо в цикле поменяйте `i < 9` на `i < 8`, либо массив объявляйте `new int[9]`.